# How to access sql files exists under c# application directory

Tags: c#, sql

I have sql files that my c# application needs them to build tables and inserting some records.

I placed these sql files in a folder within the application (Under application directory).

How can i access these files from c# application, it looks like it doesn't exists !

this is the code to test if the file exist:

```
string _myFile = @"\SQL\fileName.sql";

            if (File.Exists(_myFile))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Exists");
            }
```

the Folder under the application 
App -- > SQL --> fileName.sql

Comment: Show us the folder structure !!!

Comment: Where is that SQL folder.... Show us the Folder structure of your application  like what i have answered !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, if your using WinForms, you could use

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "mySqlFile.sql");
```

If your file is stored in a deeper folder, like ..\SQL\mySqlFile.sql just add this in the Path.Combine function as a parameter.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "SQL", "mySqlFile.sql");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access

```
Bin-->Debug--> SQL files

 string sExecutionPath =  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); // This will retrun the Debug Folder (i.e)., Exe Execution Path
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change into real path of your file like:

```
string _myFile = @"C:\SQL\fileName.sql";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to access the files

```
string appLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string xslLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(appLocation, @"SQL\fileName.sql");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(xslLocation))
            MessageBox.Show("Exists");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Exists");
```